# NSPopover buttons getting focus

Tags: swift, macos, button, nspopover

I have an NSPopover and inside it there are a few buttons.

For some reason, when I click anywhere in the popover one of the buttons becomes highlighted.  How can I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 0):

Little while ago but... select the button(s) in IB and check "Refuses first responder" in the inspector. That should do it.